# Lightning connect - Salesforce adapter

Tags: lightning-connect

I want to try Lightning connect - Salesforce Adapter. But when I try to configure it I don't see the option "Lightning Connect: Salesforce" for "Type" when creating new External Data Source. Only option I see is , "Simple URL"

Do I have to call salesforce to enable this feature or is this a paid feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Connect (unlike Salesforce-to-Salesforce) is a paid feature. You can reach out to your AE about enabling a demo, or try it out in a Dev Org.

Comment: Furthermore, it is estimated to be around USD 4,000 per month per data source.